# What's the best way to be as up to date with the network as possible

Tags: go-ethereum, events, web3-providers

I am trying to create a fast responding system based on event logs. After getting into testing the system I ran across multiple issues from the public providers I am using. I started getting errors like "header not found" and random disconnections. I tried multiple providers and got similar issues and when there are no issues, the responsiveness of the provider is very low and logs are sometimes 10 minutes late.

One option I considered is aggregating multiple providers at the same time, but that will be a real nightmare of coordination. what other options do i have to tackle this ?